# What are nested/unnested packages in Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, package, scala-2.8

In Scala 2.7, I could write:

```
package com.acme.bar

class Bar
```

.

```
package com.acme.foo

class Foo {
  new bar.Bar
}
```

This doesn't compile in Scala 2.8 -- however this does:

```
package com.acme 
package bar

class Bar
```

.

```
package com.acme
package foo

class Foo {
  new bar.Bar
}
```

1. What was the motivation for this?
2. What is the precise meaning, with regards to scope and visibility?
3. When should I use one form over the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There were several long discussions on the mailing lists about this. 
See [this thread for the problem](http://old.nabble.com/Revisiting-absolute-relative-paths-to24492690.html) and [this thread for the solution](http://old.nabble.com/Nested-package-scopes-vs.-Imports-%28Was%3A-Revisiting--absolute-relative-paths%29-tp24517644p24518578.html).

As to meaning, only the

```
package A
package B
```

form will open a scope for `A`, which makes members of `A` visible without prefix. You'd typically use this form if your project consists of several subpackages which refer to each other. On the other hand, you'd use the form

```
package A.B.C
```

If you want to integrate `C` into the package hierarchy and do not intend to access other members of `A` or `B` directly. A typical case is

```
package net.myorg.myproject
```

Here, you do not want to be vulnerable to the possibility than somebody else has defined a 
net.java package that would shadow the root level java. In Scala 2.7 you'd prevent that by using `_root_` imports. But that's ugly, and to be safe you'd have to do this almost everywhere. So the present solution is much better, IMO.

Comment: Martin just published a more detailed description, part of the 'What's new in Scala 2.8' series: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/package-clauses/packageclauses.html#

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the answers so far! Let me add two small points, and we're done!

### Visibility

The difference between nested and unnested packages only applies to scoping. **Visibility** is always based on nested packages.

```
package A

private[A] trait Secret
```

This works:

```
package A
package B

trait AB extends Secret
```

So does this:

```
package A.B

trait AB extends A.Secret
```

In both cases, the structure is interpreted as:

```
package A {
  trait Secret
  package B {
     //...
  }
}
```

### Scoping

Compare this with **scoping**, in which you could imagine this interpretation for unnested packages:

```
package A {
  private [A] trait Secret
}

package `A.B` {
   trait AB extends A.Secret

}
```

### Mix and Match

You can arbitrarily mix and match nested and unnested package:

```
package com.acme.project
package util.shazam
package blerg
```

Answer (score 9):

Doesn't it give you more control over what is being imported? For example, if there were packages:

```
package com.acme.foo.client
package com.acme.client
```

And then from within `Foo`, wasn't there an annoying ambiguity about which `client` was being referred to? For example, if you want to do a *wildcard* import from within `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  import client._ //what is being imported?
}
```

This might be much more problematic if, instead of `client`, we had a package `com.acme.java`:

```
class Foo {
    val jul = new java.util.LinkedList //compile error; cannot find util
}
```