# Confusion with a simple Scala packaging example

Tags: scala, package, scala-2.8

I've been experiencing confusion over packaging classes in Scala and importing packages. Let me start with a pair of simple source files:

### file: a/A.scala

```
package a

// Which of these imports should be used? They both seem to work.
//import a.b._
import b._

class A {
   val fieldB = new B
}
```

### file: a/b/B.scala

```
package a.b

class B
```

### usage

Compiling with scalac works without complaint with either of the imports above in A.scala

Trying to load these files in the REPL works differently:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r0-b20100714201327 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :l a/b/B.scala
Loading a/b/B.scala...
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
       package a.b
       ^
defined class B

scala> :l a/A.scala
Loading a/A.scala...
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
       package a
       ^
<console>:5: error: not found: value b
       import b._
              ^
defined class A

scala>
```

So, I have a some questions:

- What is the correct way to do that import in `A.scala` above?
- The compiler seems to be able to figure out if an import is relative to the package we are in or if it is absolute, without the `_root_`. Is that what I'm seeing?
- Am I doing this correctly in the REPL? Why does it seem so unhappy with seeing package statements, and why does the `import b._` generate an error?

Thank you

PS  I know the directory structure doesn't have to match the packaging. Doing so voluntarily is helping me to be less confused for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off you cannot define packages in the REPL. The reason for this is that your REPL-statements are actually wrapped into `object`s. That's why your :load command fails. You would need to compile your source files and add it to the classpath if you want to use packages.

When trying to resolve a symbol to be imported the compiler tries to find it in your actual scope, i.e. when you write

```
import a._
import b._
```

this will import everything from `package a` and everything from `package a.b`. If you are inside `package a` then `b` is in your scope already and the second import is sufficient.
The compiler also initially imports `scala._` so you can also use relative imports like `import xml._` to import `scala.xml._`.

In addition there is a feature called nested packages which lets you write your `B.scala` like

```
package a
package b
class B { /* .... */ }
```

which results in everything from `package a` being imported in this file.

If the compiler cannot resolve an import to a relative symbol it will look in the default package (`_root_`).

Comment: That above with two package statements isn't equivilent to `package a.b`?

Comment: @dino Mostly it is - with the difference that all of ´a´ gets imported. See also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830248/what-are-nested-unnested-packages-in-scala-2-8> and the links included.

Comment: As of now, the statement `you cannot defines packages in the REPL` is not true - you can use the `:paste raw` command to get that done - paste the entire code of a package definition, and the press `Ctrl + D` to run it.

Answer (score 0):

To load your class from the console...

`scala> :paste -raw io/hacking/yourpackage/YourClass.scala`

If your class has a main you can then invoke it with:

`scala> io.hacking.yourpackage/YourClass.main(Array())`