# Multiple packages definition

Tags: scala, package

While browsing the source code of the Scala API, I met this package definition in [scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/syntactical/StdTokenParsers.scala](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/syntactical/StdTokenParsers.scala):

```
package scala.util.parsing
package combinator
package syntactical
```

What does that mean? That the class will be available in more than one package?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is basically the same as

```
package scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical

import scala.util.parsing._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

...
```

So by "stacking" the packages the way you wrote you can get super-packages in scope. See also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830248/what-are-nested-unnested-packages-in-scala-2-8).

**[Update]** Here is a new article written by Martin Odersky about this topic: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/chained_package_clauses_in_scala.html

Answer (score 7):

The [Scala reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) mentions (chapter 9, section 9.1):

> A compilation unit consists of a sequence of packagings, import clauses, and class and object definitions, which may be preceded by a package clause.
>
> A compilation unit
>
> ```
> package p1;
> ...
> package pn;
> stats
> ```
>
> starting with one or more package clauses is equivalent to a compilation unit consisting of the packaging
>
> ```
> package p1 { ...
>   package pn {
>    stats
>   } ...
> }
> ```

See also [Organizing Code in Files and Namespaces](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mincYfsQleMC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=programming+scala+%22Organizing+Code+in+Files+and+Namespaces+%22&source=bl&ots=r43YGOPJa5&sig=t3p9zXBdzcp0Rm1jJ4S3R4-ch-I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwielLCLh5HaAhWGyKQKHVPPCkgQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=programming%20scala%20%22Organizing%20Code%20in%20Files%20and%20Namespaces%20%22&f=false) on nested packages.
(From [Programming Scala: Scalability = Functional Programming + Objects
By Dean Wampler, Alex Payne](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1734084), page 44, Chapter 2)

Comment: Last link is not available now, please correct or remove it.

Comment: @bartektartanus I have restored the link.

Comment: still not viewable. Please replace with a simple citation (book, author, publisher, page) perhaps with a link to the book homepage.