# Scala won't import package classes

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala project, but the imports don't work as designed. I tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701452/scala-import-not-working-object-database-is-not-a-member-of-package-com-me-pro), but nothing seems to fix the issue. My project is as follows:

```
- src
  - main
    - scala
      - importtest
        ImportTest.scala
      Main.scala
build.sbt
```

Imported class:

```
#/src/main/scala/importtest/ImportTest.scala
package importtest

class ImportTest {
  def run(): Unit = {
    System.out.println("boo!")
  }
}
```

My main class is:

```
#/src/main/scala/Main.scala
import importtest.ImportTest

object Main {
  def main(): Unit = {
    val i = ImportTest()
  }
}
```

My SBT build is:

```
name := "ImportTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

When I try to build, I get:

```
Error:(5, 13) not found: value ImportTest
    val i = ImportTest()
```

What is going wrong here? Why can't I import the ImportTest class?

Also, not sure if this helps, but IntelliJ will autocomplete the package name, but it cant autocomplete the class within the package - it marks it as unresolved.

Comment: [“new” keyword in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727784/432903)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing `ImportTest()` as if it was a case class. 
Because its a regular class, you need to use "new".
Change the initialization to:

```
val i = new ImportTest()
```