# Multi-line package declaration in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, package

I was surprised to [learn](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala) that there's an alternate syntax for package declaration in Scala:

```
package a
package b
package c
```

(as opposed to `package a.b.c`)

What's the use case for this alternate syntax? When should I use it instead of the standard one?

What's the design rationale behind it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541053/multiple-packages-definition and
http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/chained_package_clauses_in_scala.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the members of those enclosing packages as it were for free, "visible under their simple names" (9.2 of the spec).

That includes type definitions and functions in the package object.